# Can send PUT request via Postman but not via my Python Code

Tags: python, api, cloud-foundry, postman

I am trying to create a container using my Cloud Foundry application. When I make the request to https://v2/service_instances/temp-container via Postman with appropriate body and header, the response is 201 created.

> PUT /v2/service_instances/temp-container HTTP/1.1" 201 228 22 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" "192.168.0.126:44484" "10.1.7.79:61612" x_forwarded_for:"155.56.68.219, 192.168.0.126" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"2636e175-fbd5-42cb-6702-5a3bc96fb07e" response_time:0.213657225 app_id:"a1be4fad-c464-456b-8b7e-792da41ec93a" app_index:"1" x_b3_traceid:"126af56ae8190efa" x_b3_spanid:"126af56ae8190efa" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

But when I make the same request via my Python code, I get 401 Unauthorised.

> "PUT /v2/service_instances/temp-container HTTP/1.1" 401 228 177 "-" "python-requests/2.13.0" "192.168.0.126:49746" "10.2.7.81:64368" x_forwarded_for:"155.56.68.219, 192.168.0.126" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"85e50f55-4852-4150-7b62-c6d7ccb41e8d" response_time:0.025489445 app_id:"a1be4fad-c464-456b-8b7e-792da41ec93a" app_index:"2" x_b3_traceid:"5beaa4c44c4b9b4f" x_b3_spanid:"5beaa4c44c4b9b4f" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

The message I get is

> Full authentication is required to access this resource

I am certain I am using the same parameters and sending the same request in both the cases. What can be the possible reason?

Comment: Are you using python requests packages for sending put request data?

Comment: Please compare request header of postman and via python code. There may be something missing.

Comment: @SathishKumarVG Yes, I am using python requests package.

Comment: @ManinderSingh The headers are same, I generated the Python code from Postman and used that as well. It still gives 401.